# Not a twin prime pair test using $\gcd$ only

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences

Let $m$ be an odd positive integer such that $m=2k+1$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Let $v$ be a vector of $n$ positive integers. Let $v(i)$ be the $i$-th element of the vector. Then we start with $v(i)=m(i+1)-2$ and transform vector step by step, where step consists of finding $\gcd(v(i),v(n-i+1))$ an then adding this value to $v(i)$ and $v(n-i+1)$.

I conjecture that if we have $v(i)=m(i+1)$ for $0<i\leqslant n$ after transformation, then $m(n+3)-4$ and $m(n+3)-2$ is a probable twin prime pair. In other words, if we have $\gcd(v(i),v(n-i+1))>1$ at some step, then $m(n+3)-4$ and $m(n+3)-2$ is guarantee not a twin prime pair.

Here is the PARI/GP prog to check it numerically:

```
b1(n, m) = my(v1); v1=vector(n, i, m*(i + 1) - 2); for(i=1, n, my(A=gcd(v1[i], v1[n - i + 1])); v1[i] += A; v1[n - i + 1] += A); v1
b2(n, m) = b1(n, m) == vector(n, i, m*(i + 1))
b3(n, m) = [n, isprime(m*(n + 3) - 4), isprime(m*(n+3)-2)]
my(z=1, m=2^100 + 1); for(k=1, 59, while(!(b2(z, m)), z++); print(b3(z, m)); z++;);
my(z=1, m=2^100 + 1); for(k=1, 59, while(!(isprime(m*(z + 3) - 4) + isprime(m*(z + 3) - 2) == 2), z++);
```

As you can see, every twin prime pair of the form $m(n+3)-4$ and $m(n+3)-2$ appears in the list of probable twin prime pairs.

I also conjecture that list of probable twin prime pairs of the form $m(n+3)-4$ and $m(n+3)-2$ contains finite number of not twin prime pairs and the filtered values of $n$ after some $n=q$ is always a twin prime pair.

Is there a way to prove it?